# C# How do I check USB Ports with USB Hub and used Controller?

Tags: c#, controller, usb, port-scanning

I am currently trying to scan all USB Ports with their USB Hub (check if it is Root or not) and to which controller they are connectet.

To make it more visible:

```
USB Port1 (nothing plugged in)   -> USB Hub1   |                 |-> Controller 1
USB Port2 (Keyboard plugged in)  ->            |-> USB Root Hub  |-> Controller 2
USB Port3 (nothing plugged in)   -> USB Hub2   |                 |
USB Port4 (nothing plugged in)   ->            |-> USB Root Hub  |-> Controller3 (Mainboard)
```

I want to show the User all ports and connected Hubs as a tree. And if the USB Port with its controller are in use or not.

I hope you guys can understand what I am trying to describe. If you could give me some Keywords or even Code snippets i would greatly appreciate it.

PS.: Sorry for my bad english.

Here is the Code so far (I am using the .NetFramework 4.5.x):

***USBPortScanner Class:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace USBPortScanner

{
    class USBPortScanner
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var usbDevices = GetUSBDevices();
            foreach (var usbDevice in usbDevices)
            {
                //Prints all defined porperties, they need to be defined in the USBDeviceInfo.cs!
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}\r\nCaption: {1}\r\nError Code: {2}\r\nDevice ID: {3}\r\nSystem Name: {4}\r\nStatus: {5}",
                    usbDevice.Name, usbDevice.Caption, usbDevice.ConfigManagerErrorCode, usbDevice.DeviceID, usbDevice.SystemName, usbDevice.Status);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
        //Sets the Properties for the device variable
        static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
        {
            List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

            //Scanning all USBHubs with WMI
            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub"))
            {
                using (ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get())
                {
                    foreach (ManagementObject device in collection)
                    {

                        //To show all available data
                        //Console.WriteLine(device.Path);

                        //foreach (PropertyData prop in device.Properties)
                        //{
                        //    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + prop.Value);
                        //}

                        //Console.WriteLine();

                        //Adds properties to device
                        devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(device));
                    }
                }
            }

            return devices;
        }
    }
}
```

***USBDeviceInfo Class:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;

namespace USBPortScanner
{

    class USBDeviceInfo
    {
        public USBDeviceInfo(ManagementObject device)
        {
            this.Name = device.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();
            this.Caption = device.GetPropertyValue("Caption").ToString();

            if (device.GetPropertyValue("ConfigManagerErrorCode") != null)
            {
                this.ConfigManagerErrorCode = (ErrorCode)device.GetPropertyValue("ConfigManagerErrorCode");
            }
            else
            {
                this.ConfigManagerErrorCode = ErrorCode.Device_is_not_present_not_working_properly_or_does_not_have_all_of_its_drivers_installed;
            }

            this.DeviceID = device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID").ToString();
            this.SystemName = device.GetPropertyValue("SystemName").ToString();
            this.Status = device.GetPropertyValue("Status").ToString();
        }

        //Sets the variables above usable for our purpose in the Program.cs
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Caption { get; private set; }
        public ErrorCode ConfigManagerErrorCode { get; private set; }
        public string DeviceID { get; private set; }
        public string SystemName { get; private set; }
        public string Status { get; private set; }
    }
    enum ErrorCode : uint
    {
        Device_is_working_properly = 0,
        Device_is_not_configured_correctly = 1,
        Windows_cannot_load_the_driver_for_this_device = 2,
        Driver_for_this_device_might_be_corrupted_or_the_system_may_be_low_on_memory_or_other_resources = 3,
        Device_is_not_working_properly_One_of_its_drivers_or_the_registry_might_be_corrupted = 4,
        Driver_for_the_device_requires_a_resource_that_Windows_cannot_manage = 5,
        Boot_configuration_for_the_device_conflicts_with_other_devices = 6,
        Cannot_filter = 7,
        Driver_loader_for_the_device_is_missing = 8,
        Device_is_not_working_properly_The_controlling_firmware_is_incorrectly_reporting_the_resources_for_the_device = 9,
        Device_cannot_start = 10,
        Device_failed = 11,
        Device_cannot_find_enough_free_resources_to_use = 12,
        Windows_cannot_verify_the_device_resources = 13,
        Device_cannot_work_properly_until_the_computer_is_restarted = 14,
        Device_is_not_working_properly_due_to_a_possible_reenumeration_problem = 15,
        Windows_cannot_identify_all_of_the_resources_that_the_device_uses = 16,
        Device_is_requesting_an_unknown_resource_type = 17,
        Device_drivers_must_be_reinstalled = 18,
        Failure_using_the_VxD_loader = 19,
        Registry_might_be_corrupted = 20,
        System_failure_If_changing_the_device_driver_is_ineffective_see_the_hardware_documentation_Windows_is_removing_the_device = 21,
        Device_is_disabled = 22,
        System_failure_If_changing_the_device_driver_is_ineffective_see_the_hardware_documentation = 23,
        Device_is_not_present_not_working_properly_or_does_not_have_all_of_its_drivers_installed = 24,
        Windows_is_still_setting_up_the_device = 25 | 26,
        Device_does_not_have_valid_log_configuration = 27,
        Device_drivers_are_not_installed = 28,
        Device_is_disabled_The_device_firmware_did_not_provide_the_required_resources = 29,
        Device_is_using_an_IRQ_resource_that_another_device_is_using = 30,
        Device_is_not_working_properly_Windows_cannot_load_the_required_device_drivers = 31,

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution myself. The Code below is a example i used from another site. I hope it will help the community too.

source: http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?example=545&ver=vcs&PHPSESSID=70ba6845606a96b355ab7f772fb14386

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Linq;

namespace DeviceEnumerator
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var deviceTree = new DeviceTree();

            foreach (var deviceClass in Win32.DeviceClasses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n{0}:", deviceClass.Value);

                foreach (var device in deviceTree.DeviceNodes
                    .Where(d => d.ClassGuid == deviceClass.Key))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "\t{1}: {0}",
                        device.Description,
                        device.EnumeratorName);
                }
            }

            Console.Write("\n\nAny key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class DeviceTree : IDisposable
    {
        private IntPtr _machineHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        private IntPtr _rootDeviceHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        private DeviceNode _rootNode;

        // flat collection of all devices found
        private List< DeviceNode > _deviceNodes;

        public DeviceNode RootNode
        {
            get
            {
                return this._rootNode;
            }
        }

        public List< DeviceNode > DeviceNodes
        {
            get
            {
                return this._deviceNodes;
            }
        }

        public DeviceTree()
        {
            EnumerateDevices();
        }

        ~DeviceTree()
        {
            this.Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                this._deviceNodes.Clear();
            }

            this.DisconnectFromMachine();
        }

        private void EnumerateDevices()
        {
            this.DisconnectFromMachine();

            // local machine assumed
            if (Win32.CM_Connect_Machine(
                null, ref this._machineHandle) != 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                Win32.CM_Locate_DevNode_Ex(
                    ref this._rootDeviceHandle,
                    0,
                    0,
                    this._machineHandle);

                // recursive enumeration
                this._rootNode = new DeviceNode(
                    this._rootDeviceHandle,
                    null,
                    this._machineHandle);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.DisconnectFromMachine();

                if (this._rootNode != null)
                {
                    this._deviceNodes = this._rootNode
                        .Flatten(node => node.Children).ToList();
                }
            }
        }

        private void DisconnectFromMachine()
        {
            if (this._machineHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Win32.CM_Disconnect_Machine(this._machineHandle);
                this._machineHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
    }

    public class DeviceNode : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly DeviceNode _parentDevice;
        private readonly List< DeviceNode > _children;
        private readonly IntPtr _deviceHandle;
        private readonly IntPtr _machineHandle;

        private readonly Dictionary< int, string >
            _deviceProperties;

        public DeviceNode ParentDevice
        {
            get
            {
                return _parentDevice;
            }
        }

        public Dictionary< int, string > DeviceProperties
        {
            get
            {
                return _deviceProperties;
            }
        }

        public List< DeviceNode > Children
        {
            get
            {
                return this._children;
            }
        }

        public Guid ClassGuid
        {
            get
            {
                string buffer =
                    this.GetProperty(Win32.DevRegProperty.ClassGuid);

                var guid = new Guid();

                if (buffer.Length >= 32)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        guid = new Guid(buffer);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        guid = new Guid();
                    }
                }

                return guid;
            }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return
                    GetProperty(Win32.DevRegProperty.DeviceDescription);
            }
        }

        public string FriendlyName
        {
            get
            {
                return
                    GetProperty(Win32.DevRegProperty.FriendlyName);
            }
        }

        public string EnumeratorName
        {
            get
            {
                return
                    GetProperty(Win32.DevRegProperty.EnumeratorName);
            }
        }

        public string LocationInfo
        {
            get
            {
                return
                    GetProperty(Win32.DevRegProperty.LocationInfo);
            }
        }

        public DeviceNode(IntPtr deviceHandle, DeviceNode parentDevice)
            : this(
                    deviceHandle, 
                    parentDevice, 
                    parentDevice._machineHandle)
        {
        }

        public DeviceNode(
            IntPtr deviceHandle,
            DeviceNode parentDevice,
            IntPtr machineHandle)
        {
            _deviceProperties = new Dictionary< int, string >();
            _children = new List< DeviceNode >();

            _deviceHandle = deviceHandle;
            _machineHandle = machineHandle;
            _parentDevice = parentDevice;

            EnumerateDeviceProperties();
            EnumerateChildren();
        }

        private string GetProperty(
            Win32.DevRegProperty devRegProperty)
        {
            return GetProperty((int)devRegProperty);
        }

        private string GetProperty(int index)
        {
            string buffer;
            var result = this._deviceProperties
                .TryGetValue(index, out buffer);
            return result ? buffer : string.Empty;
        }

        private void EnumerateDeviceProperties()
        {
            for (var index = 0; index < 64; index++)
            {
                uint bufsize = 2048;

                IntPtr buffer = 
                    Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)bufsize);

                var result = 
                    Win32.CM_Get_DevNode_Registry_Property_Ex(
                        _deviceHandle,
                        index,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        buffer,
                        ref bufsize,
                        0,
                        _machineHandle);

                var propertyString = result == 0
                    ? Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer) 
                    : string.Empty;

                _deviceProperties.Add(index, propertyString);

                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
            }
        }

        private void EnumerateChildren()
        {
            IntPtr ptrFirstChild = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (Win32.CM_Get_Child_Ex(
                ref ptrFirstChild, 
                _deviceHandle, 
                0, 
                _machineHandle) != 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            var ptrChild = ptrFirstChild;
            var ptrSibling = IntPtr.Zero;

            do
            {
                var childDevice = new DeviceNode(ptrChild, this);
                _children.Add(childDevice);

                if (Win32.CM_Get_Sibling_Ex(
                    ref ptrSibling, 
                    ptrChild, 
                    0, 
                    _machineHandle) != 0) break;

                ptrChild = ptrSibling;
            }
            while (true);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _deviceProperties.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    internal static class LinqExtensionMethods
    {
        public static IEnumerable< T > Return< T >(T element)
        {
            yield return element;
        }

        public static IEnumerable< T > StartWith< T >(
            this IEnumerable< T > list, T element)
        {
            return Return(element).Concat(list);
        }

        public static IEnumerable< TEntity > Flatten< TEntity >(
            this TEntity element,
            Func< TEntity, IEnumerable< TEntity > > childSelector)
        {
            if (childSelector(element) != null)
                return childSelector(element)
                    .SelectMany(child => child.Flatten(childSelector))
                    .StartWith(element);

            var items = new List< TEntity > { element };
            return items;
        }
    }

    public static class Win32
    {
        // this is a partial list
        public static readonly
            Dictionary< Guid, string > DeviceClasses =
            new Dictionary< Guid, string >
            {
                { new Guid("{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"), 
                    "Disk Drives" },
                { new Guid("{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"), 
                    "Display Adapters" },
                { new Guid("{4d36e96b-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"), 
                    "Keyboards" },
                { new Guid("{4d36e96f-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"), 
                    "Mice" },
            };

        public enum DevRegProperty : uint
        {
            DeviceDescription = 1,
            HardwareId = 2,
            CompatibleIds = 3,
            Unused0 = 4,
            Service = 5,
            Unused1 = 6,
            Unused2 = 7,
            Class = 8,
            ClassGuid = 9,
            Driver = 0x0a,
            ConfigFlags = 0x0b,
            Mfg = 0x0c,
            FriendlyName = 0x0d,
            LocationInfo = 0x0e,
            PhysicalDeviceObjectName = 0x0f,
            Capabilities = 0x10,
            UiNumber = 0x11,
            UpperFilters = 0x12,
            LowerFilters = 0x13,
            BusTypeGuid = 0x014,
            LegacyBusType = 0x15,
            BusNumber = 0x16,
            EnumeratorName = 0x17,
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern uint GetLogicalDrives();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetDriveType(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string rootPathName);

        [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Connect_Machine(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string uncServerName,
            ref IntPtr machineHandle);

        [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Disconnect_Machine(
            IntPtr machineHandle);

        [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Locate_DevNode_Ex(
            ref IntPtr deviceHandle,
            int deviceId,
            uint flags,
            IntPtr machineHandle);

        [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Get_Child_Ex(
            ref IntPtr childDeviceHandle,
            IntPtr parentDeviceHandle,
            uint flags,
            IntPtr machineHandle);

        [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
        public static extern int CM_Get_Sibling_Ex(
            ref IntPtr siblingDeviceHandle,
            IntPtr deviceHandle,
            uint flags,
            IntPtr machineHandle);

        [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
        public static extern int 
            CM_Get_DevNode_Registry_Property_Ex(
                IntPtr deviceHandle,
                int property,
                IntPtr regDataType,
                IntPtr outBuffer,
                ref uint size,
                int flags,
                IntPtr machineHandle);
    }
}
```