# How can I get the free USB ports in c#?

Tags: c#, winapi, usb, wmi

I am developing C# application which needs to find any USB port is free for use or not.

Is there any C# class or WMI query to determine USB Port is free for use or not?

Suppose,
If a machine has 5 USB ports and out of which 2 are already occupied by mouse ,keyboard
and remaining 3 are free.
So I need to identify these ports which are not in use.

Is there any win32 class for this so I can use P/Invoke

Regards,

Amol.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965098/c-sharp-how-do-i-check-usb-ports-with-usb-hub-and-used-controller

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3331509/4939144) answer. I think you need to inspect `Availability` property of each [Win32_USBHub](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine if device is connected to that port. However, there may be difficulties with USB hubs.

```
if ((int)device.GetPropertyValue("Availability")>3)
    //port is free
```